# SlickJs controls do not work after being re-loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slick.js

I have a slickJS carousel that I am using with ~ 12 menu items. On a message from a websocket connection, the page is re-loaded with up-to-date information via AJAX, the HTML including the slickJS carousel. The carousel re-initializes fine cosmetically, however the controls (arrows, click-n-grab) do not work. I can pick a new 'menu item' from the current view but nothing else is functional. I have also tried manually re-initializing slick using

```
$('.my-menu-list').slick('unslick').slick('reinit');
```

but that yields the same result. For reference, my init command for slick is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.my-menu-list').slick({
      arrows: true,
      infinite: true,
      lazyLoad: 'progressive',
      speed: 600,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      initialSlide: $('.my-menu-list.active').data('slick-index')
  });
});
```

and it is loaded from an external file.